# How can I get the contents of an external script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a handlebars template in a public directory. I'd like to access the contents of this file with JavaScript. Here's the code for the script:

```
<script id="test_template" type="text/template" src="/templates/test.hbs"></script>
```

If I dump out the contents of the file inside the script tag (instead of using the "src" attribute) I can easily get at the contents, but then I won't get any caching.

Is it possible to get the contents of this file without using an AJAX call?

Comment: Why not use an AJAX call like getScript()? http://api.jquery.com/getScript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the contents of this file without using an AJAX call?

No, you'll need to use an AJAX call.